# I want to show products by category using the . feature (.filter)

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner to Django, I want to show products by category using the .feature (.filter),
I tried many times but I couldn't do it I hope someone can help me.

Please write the code with explanation

**MODELS:**

```
from django.db import models
        
        # Create your models here.
        
        class Category(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
            slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
        
        class Product(models.Model):
            Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
            slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
            description = models.TextField(max_length=350, null=False, blank=False)
            image = models.ImageField( null=False, blank=False)
            quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
        
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

**URLS:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('f/<str:slug>', views.fd, name="fd"),
    path('category', views.category, name="category"),
    path('category/<str:slug>', views.categoryslug, name="categoryslug"), 
]
```

**VIEWS:**

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'Pr': Product.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', context)


def fd(request, slug):
    context = {
        'gfd' : Product.objects.get(slug=slug),
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/product.html', context)


    
def category(request):
    context = {
        'Categorys': Category.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/category.html', context)
```

Please write the code with explanation

i need to show product by category

Answer (score 1):

pages/category.html

```
{% for cat in Categorys %}
    {{ cat.name }}
    {% for obj in cat.product_set.all %}
        {{ obj.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You don't need to add a related_name. The implicit default would be `product_set`.

Comment: You right. This is an old habit to me

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you need an implementation for `categoryslug`, presumably a page for showing a category and its products, something like

```
def categoryslug(request, slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {
        'category': category,
        'products': category.product_set.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/products-in-category.html', context)
```

would be a good bare-bones start.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question. I want to show a product page by category. The name of the product is done. Can you help me?                                                                             url   http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/phone/redmi-8

Comment: url path('category/<str:slug>/<str:proslug>', views.catproslug, name="catproslug")                            how to creat view for this url I couldn't do it I'm a newbie